# Nested json in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a json column `day_data` which has data in json format. How do I achieve the expected output using Hive?

input:

`{"_id":"1","name":"abc","attribs":[{"minutes":0,"name":"sedentary"},{"minutes":0,"name":"lightly"},{"minutes":0,"name":"fairly"},{"minutes":28,"name":"very"}],"validated":true}`

output:

`id  name    attrib_minutes  attrib_name validated
1   abc     0               sedentary   true
1   abc     0               lightly     true
1   abc     0               fairly      true
1   abc     28              very        true`

I am able to extract id, name and validated fields using `get_json_object` command,

`select
get_json_object(day_data,'$._id') as id,
get_json_object(day_data,'$.name') as name,
get_json_object(day_data,'$.validated') as validated
from temp_table;`

How do I extract the nested json attributes (attrib_minutes and attrib_name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  j.id
       ,j.name
       ,get_json_object  (day_data,concat('$.attribs[',e.i,'].minutes'))    as attrib_minutes
       ,get_json_object  (day_data,concat('$.attribs[',e.i,'].name'))       as attrib_name
       ,j.validated

from                    temp_table t
        lateral view    json_tuple  (day_data,'_id','name','validated')  j as id,name,validated
        lateral view    posexplode  (split(get_json_object (day_data,'$.attribs[*].name'),'","')) e as i,x
;
```

---

```
j.id    j.name  attrib_minutes  attrib_name j.validated
1   abc 0   sedentary   true
1   abc 0   lightly true
1   abc 0   fairly  true
1   abc 28  very    true
```